# Can't retarget project from NET 6.0 to NET framework 4.8 (VS Community 2022)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, .net-4.8

I have all the necessary packages installed:
[image]

And yet I don't see that framework in dropdown menu:
[image]

So I've got request to retarget my project from .NET 6.0 to .NET 4.8 due to tools I will need to use in the future and their compability.

If there is any other way to achieve said retargetting I'm open to it. I just can't find myself rewriting whole project from the scratch in .NET 4.8 framework

Comment: you have included the tag [tag:asp.net]; if this really is an aspnet project: this will not be a simple change - aspnet changed quite a lot between legacy netframework and modern .net; also: frankly, IMO it is a VERY BAD IDEA to focus on net48 at this point - I would strongly suggest pushing back on that and challenging where that motivation is coming from, because that is the *opposite* of what most folks should be doing

Comment: " I just can't find myself rewriting whole project from the scratch in .NET 4.8 framework". If you have already written that in Net 6 presumably changing the target framework is the smallest problem here. Presumably big parts of your code simply won't just compile. Try setting up a new NET 4.8 project and move code over and see what happens. Doing it this way makes it presumably easier to get an estimate how large the downgrading problem actually will be.

Comment: As noted, the .net core framwork is "different" then the .net framwork. So, ZERO surprise that you can't just flip or change the project from a WHOLE NEW different framework. As noted, I would simple create a new .net framework, and then use add->existing and pull in the .net core parts one by one. The edit below does suggest you can change to a total new and different framework - but I did not think that was possible. So, this is a big change, and is much like saying you want to re-write your project in vb.net - so .net core is different. To be fair, coding is much the same.

Answer (score 4):

Edit the csproj; i.e. from

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
```

to

```
<TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
```

or perhaps

```
<TargetFrameworks>net6.0;net48</TargetFrameworks>
```

in the latter case, using a few `#if`/`#else`/`#endif` as needed to shim over any platform specifics - in particular looking at `#if NETFRAMEWORK`, `#if NET6_0_OR_GREATER`, etc

Comment: If this doesn't work, you need to do **additional edits** to the project file. See Microsoft article [How to roll back solution from .net6 to Framework 4.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/955732/how-to-roll-back-solution-from-net6-to-framework-4)